# Why setBackground with Drawable can not be completely filled

Tags: android

Actual display, its height should be three rows, but only two rows?

```
myView = new ImageView(mContext) //or new TextView();
int height = 128 * 3;
int width = 128;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
layoutParams.setMargins(xxx, xxx);
myView.setBackground(xxx);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Full Code:

```
ImageView myView = new ImageView(this);
        //int height = 128 * 3;
        //int width = 128;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        myView.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.art_clouds));


        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(myView);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Also See:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: @Mike_ShangJun if the answer worked then you can accept the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Also See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 1):

You're using pixels ,,, try this

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int height = (int) 128 * 3 * scale;
int width = (int) 128 * scale;
```